# How to set up URL rewrite on IIS 7.5, Windows 2008 R2

Tags: iis-7.5

My domain name is hosted externally and only supports AAAA redirects (domain to IP)
At the moment application.domain.xxx and login.domain.xxx redirects to my web server IP.
How can I set up IIS 7.5 (Windows 2008 R2) so that incoming requests are redirected:
application.domain.xxx redirects to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/application.aspx
login.domain.xxx redirects to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/login.aspx
I'm not sure where to start.